# Uable to open exported excel file

Tags: excel, asp.net-core, export, epplus

I am creating an asp.net Core API with an endpoint to export data as excel file.
I have added the nuget package EPPlus.Core.

This is my code so far:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
...
Public class DataService
{
...
  public Byte[] Export(ExportRequest request){
    var data = _repository(request);
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
      package.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Persons";

      var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Persons");

      //Headers
      worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Id";
      worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Name";

      //Values
      var row = 2;
      foreach (var person in data.Persons)
      {
        worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = person.Id;
        worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value = person.Name;
        row++;
      }
      return package.GetAsByteArray();
  }
}


public class PersonController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{version:apiVersion}/[controller]/Export")]
    [SwaggerResponse(400, typeof(Exception), "Error in request")]
    [SwaggerResponse(500, typeof(Exception), "Error on server")]
    public IActionResult Export([FromBody] ExportRequest request)
    {
        Byte[] byteArray = _projectService.ExportRegistrations(request);
        if (byteArray != null)
        {
            return File(byteArray, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "persons.xlsx");
        }
        return BadRequest("Failure");
    }
}
```

I test my API using swagger and get a file downloaded named persons.xlsx.
But I am not able to open it.
I get the two following promts:

We found a problem in some of the contents of "persons.xlsx", should we try to restore as much as possible? If you trust the source of the workbook, click Yes.

The file "persons.xlsx" can not be opened because the file format or file type name is invalid. Verify that the file is not corrupted and that the file type name matches the file format.

And then an empty excel document.

Answer (score 0):

i have also facing the same problem,

The workaround is directly open the url via browser or using postman.